# My app is down on Heroku, no errors when run "heroku run rails test", but many errors on running "heroku run rails console"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, console

my rails application is down when pushing it to heroku

this is the output of heroku application logs

```
2018-06-09T16:53:56.213028+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cryptic-everglades-17685.herokuapp.com request_id=e02b7de8-01c6-4a66-9118-4f26407edae9 fwd="156.212.233.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-09T16:53:56.762020+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cryptic-everglades-17685.herokuapp.com request_id=f91d7fe2-509d-4bf1-b32c-73ae9a700e1e fwd="156.212.233.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I tried running `heroku restart`, then `heroku run rails console` .. and I got these errors,

```
Running rails console on ⬢ cryptic-everglades-17685... up, run.7205 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    38: from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    37: from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    36: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    35: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    34: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    33: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    32: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    31: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    30: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:96:in `perform'
    29: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:16:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    28: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
    27: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require'
    26: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    24: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    23: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    21: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    20: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    19: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    18: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    16: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    15: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    14: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    13: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    12: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    11: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    10: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `each'
     9: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
     8: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
     7: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
     6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
     5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
     4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
     3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
     2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
     1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/app/app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant CarrierWave (NameError)
```

my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.5.1"

gem 'rails',        '5.1.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.12'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.10.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

excuse me but I'm still newbie, and this was just a registration system that I was trying to build using "rails tutorial" book.. knowing that the application is working well on my pc localhost,

Comment: Can you show Gemfile?

Comment: sure, added it to the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see here you have an error with CarrierWave. You seams to call it in one of your program files but it is not there in your gem file.

Check througg all your config files incase you imported some of Ur codes from existing project.

Comment: I installed CarrierWave gem and the error is solved, thanks bro you saved my life <3 , but I got a question, how did you know that it was the carrierwave gem which caused the error ?

Answer (score 2):

In the `application.rb` add this line like

```
require 'carrierwave'
```

Then add/commit cycle to push heroku again